# How to delete last character in a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

Building a string for post request in the following way,

```
  var itemsToAdd = sl.SelProds.ToList();
  if (sl.SelProds.Count() != 0)
  {
      foreach (var item in itemsToAdd)
      {
        paramstr = paramstr + string.Format("productID={0}&", item.prodID.ToString());
      }
  }
```

after I get resulting `paramstr`, I need to delete last character `&` in it

How to delete last character in a **string** using C#?

Comment: Guess it's better to just not add it in the first place, but otherwise you can try paramstr.Substring(0, paramstr.Length - 1)

Comment: In case your prodID is allowed to contain arbitrary characters, especially `&`, you need to make sure it gets properly escaped, like e.g. the answer of @MarcGravell does.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

build it with `string.Join` instead:

```
var parameters = sl.SelProds.Select(x=>"productID="+x.prodID).ToArray();
paramstr = string.Join("&", parameters);
```

`string.Join` takes a seperator (`"&"`) and and array of strings (`parameters`), and inserts the seperator between each element of the array.

Comment: Worth noting that this is helpful if you don't want to have an & sign at the end of the string.

Comment: I knew this was in Ruby, had no idea it was in C# and I'm a .net dev. I feel so embarrassed lol

Comment: I can't believe this was the chosen answer... the one just below this by @BrianRasmussen is so much simpler.

Comment: @FastTrack It solved the root problem, versus answering the question in the title.  My complaint: if you are going to be fluent, why not just do it all in one line.

Answer (score 241):

Personally I would go with Rob's suggestion, but if you want to remove one (or more) specific trailing character(s) you can use [`TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx). E.g.

```
paramstr = paramstr.TrimEnd('&');
```

Comment: Be aware that TrimEnd will remove all trailing occurrences of that character '&'... so if the string ends with '&&&' then TrimEnd will remove all 3 of those '&', not just the last one. That may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @DougS FWIW I did writer "remove one (or more)".

Comment: +1 for a simple solution, that can thus be easily used as a component for other problems.

I was searching for a solution to creating a path from multiple parts ensuring I did not have double or missing slashes. Combining TrimEnd and TrimStart with this technique ensures this.

Comment: @Joeppie: suggest using `Path.Combine`, which understands all path separators. Leastways use `Trim` which does start and end in one go.

Comment: @Nigel the trouble I have with Path.Combine is that if the second argument starts with a slash, it is interpreted as an absolute path, and the result is the absolute path; this is something I prefer to 'save'  people calling my code from. Good point on the Trim, though :)

Answer (score 22):

```
string source;
// source gets initialized
string dest;
if (source.Length > 0)
{
    dest = source.Substring(0, source.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
paramstr.Remove((paramstr.Length-1),1);
```

Comment: Would you consider explaining your answer a little bit, so that others who come along have a better idea why you suggested it?

Comment: [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15201203/1497596) by @Altaf Patel uses the sibling method [String.Remove Method (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is arguably more straightforward in this situation. However, its good to know about [String.Remove Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which offers the ability to trim a substring of arbitrary length from anywhere within the source string.

Answer (score 13):

I would just not add it in the first place:

```
 var sb = new StringBuilder();

 bool first = true;
 foreach (var foo in items) {
    if (first)
        first = false;
    else
        sb.Append('&');

    // for example:
    var escapedValue = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(foo);

    sb.Append(key).Append('=').Append(escapedValue);
 }

 var s = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I won't say anything about the readability of this snippet, but this is the way I'd do it.

Comment: It's also cheap and easy to just shorten the StringBuilder's length by one after the loop is done.

Comment: +1 for not adding it instead of removing it, for using a StringBuilder instead of +=, and for chaining appends instead of concatenating and appending. :)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the "if" operator is called "n" times.

Answer (score 11):

```
string str="This is test string.";
str=str.Remove(str.Length-1);
```

Comment: From [String.Remove Method (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): *"Returns a new string in which all the characters in the current instance, beginning at a specified position and continuing through the last position, have been deleted."*

Answer (score 7):

It's better if you use `string.Join`.

```
 class Product
 {
   public int ProductID { get; set; }
 }
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
      {   
         new Product { ProductID = 1 },
         new Product { ProductID = 2 },
         new Product { ProductID = 3 }
      };
   string theURL = string.Join("&", products.Select(p => string.Format("productID={0}", p.ProductID)));
   Console.WriteLine(theURL);
 }
```

Comment: You are missing `.ToArray()` in your `Join` statement. +1 though. Helped me.

Comment: @desaivv: No, I was using this overload: `public static string Join<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> values)`, it's new in C# 4.0 :)

Comment: Ahh my bad. Still using VS2008 with 3.0

Answer (score 5):

It's good practice to use a `StringBuilder` when concatenating a lot of strings and you can then use the Remove method to get rid of the final character.

```
StringBuilder paramBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in itemsToAdd)
{
    paramBuilder.AppendFormat(("productID={0}&", item.prodID.ToString());
}

if (paramBuilder.Length > 1)
    paramBuilder.Remove(paramBuilder.Length-1, 1);

string s = paramBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: I also remembered you can use `paramBuilder.Length - 1` to remove the last character, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
paramstr.Remove((paramstr.Length-1),1);
```

This does work to remove a single character from the end of a string. But if I use it to remove, say, **4** characters, this doesn't work:

```
paramstr.Remove((paramstr.Length-4),1);
```

As an alternative, I have used this approach instead:

```
DateFrom = DateFrom.Substring(0, DateFrom.Length-4);
```

Comment: Using [String.Remove Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), to remove **4** characters from the end of a string: `result = source.Remove((source.Length - 4), 4);`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `StringBuilder` `extension method`.

```
public static StringBuilder RemoveLast(this StringBuilder sb, string value)
{
    if(sb.Length < 1) return sb;
    sb.Remove(sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(value), value.Length);
    return sb;
}
```

then use:

```
yourStringBuilder.RemoveLast(",");
```