# how to remove the extra AND from the loop

Tags: c#, .net, string

```
foreach (string word in allTheseWords)
{
allTheseStringsWhereClause = allTheseStringsWhereClause + 
                             " report=" + 
                             word + 
                             " AND ";
}
```

The problem is after the loop, the SQL clause has an extra `AND` at the end of it.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Don't generate your SQL from concatenating strings.  It's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: was the editing necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of question is very common and here's the proof.

1. [Delete last char of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901360/delete-last-char-of-string)
2. [How to delete last character in a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745859/how-to-delete-last-character-in-a-string-in-c)
3. [Finding the last index of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056749/finding-the-last-index-of-an-array)

But here my simple solution

```
        string[] allTheseWords = { "try", "test", "let" };
        string whereLine = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in allTheseWords)
                whereLine += "report = " + item.ToString() + " and ";
        string final = whereLine.Remove(whereLine.Length - 5);
        Console.WriteLine(final);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 13):

you can alternatively use `LINQ`

```
string _final = string.Join(" AND ", (allTheseWords.Select(x => "report=" + x)));
```

Comment: You are using the wrong variable. `allTheseStringsWhereClause` is a string. The words are in the `allTheseWords` variable.

Answer (score 4):

By inserting user input into a sql where clause you are introducing a vector for a **SQL Injection Attack**.  Do no use this approach.  Basically you want to use SQL Parameters.

```
where report in @allTheseWords
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

**EDIT**

See the answer with the most votes in [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause) for how to really do parameterised in query.

Comment: The question is about string manipulation, not SQL best practices. This is not an answer to his question, and would better serve as a comment to the question than an answer.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple, I so strongly disagree.  The OP specifically mentions `allTheseStringsWhereClause`, which implies a SQL where clause.  This is **WRONG** and must be corrected.

Comment: Er. What database lets you pass an array as a parameter?

Comment: @RichardSchneider what if the `WHERE` clause the OP is referring is used to filter the dataset? anyway, that is still **NOT** the correct way of parameterizing `IN` clause.

Comment: @Random832.  Sorry I was just taking the easy way with out doing the research (I always use an ORM) thats why I said basically).  However now see the answer with the most votes in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause

Comment: @RichardSchneider - thank you for your insight. Although, I didn't ask about SQL Injection; you were able to deduce that I am making an SQL Query. So my question is how do I pass an array as a Parameter?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to add a bogus always-true clause (and move the AND):

```
string allTheseStringsWhereClause = "WHERE 1=1";
foreach (string word in allTheseWords)
{
allTheseStringsWhereClause = allTheseStringsWhereClause + 
                             " AND report=" + 
                             word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need LINQ, just use `Join`:

```
string whereClause = " report=" + String.Join(" AND report=", allTheseWords);
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this without hard coding a substring method is to try an Aggregate LINQ query

```
var result = allTheseWords.Aggregate(allTheseStringsWhereClause, (current, word) => current + " report=" + word + " AND ");
```

Answer (score -3):

Easy. You just need to do allTheseStringsWhereClause.substr(0,-4) and that's it!